# ViewModel onCleared() called on screen rotation

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt to inject a `ViewModel` into a fragment. But on screen rotation, `ViewModel.onCleared()` is called. Is this expected behaviour? I always thought `ViewModel` survives screen rotation.

Due to this, the `ViewModel` is recreated which I verified by comparing the `ViewModel` hash code on screen rotation.

Here is my fragment code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels()
    private var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false
        )
        binding.viewModel = dashboardViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.adapter = adapter
        setObservers()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()

    }
}
```

and the `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DashboardViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    init {
        //Some code
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Timber.e("cleared")
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is it expected behaviour?" -- without a [mcve], we cannot tell you if the behavior is expected or not. For example, if you are manually replacing the fragment as part of the configuration change, you will get a new viewmodel instance to go along with the new fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added the code snippet. Please have a look. I am not manually replacing the fragment. In fact I have not written anything to handle configuration change.

Comment: What happens when you comment out the nullification of the inner binding reference within the onDestroyView?

Comment: @BonanzaDriver still the same behaviour. onCleared() called.

Comment: Can you include your `DashboardViewModel` code? Or at least the class declaration with the annotations etc.

Comment: @HenryTwist I have updated the viewmodel code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed .addToBackStack when you run this fragment.
But most importantly: make sure that the fragment is not recreated again when you rotate the screen, for example, using

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
...
}
```

inside of onCreate, onCreateView and so on

Answer (score 0):

This is not what should be happening with a `ViewModel`. As you said they are designed to survive recreation due to an orientation change.

What seems to be happening here is that you're recreating your `Fragment` whenever the screen is rotated, in `onCreate` of an activity or something similar. This then causes the `ViewModel` to get cleared and re-instantiated.

Comment: Oh Okay. I don't think I am doing that, but I will check again for sure. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: If you don't find the issue maybe you could edit your question to include where you're adding the fragment, then I'll take another look!